# add a ndcg as metric in keras model.compile()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following the tutorial here https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/dcn to construct a dcn model.

For the metrics, I want to return ndcg. And by this information here, https://www.tensorflow.org/ranking/api_docs/python/tfr/keras/metrics/DCGMetric
I added this

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', metrics=[tfr.keras.metrics.DCGMetric()])
```

But after model evaluation, I still receive rmse only.

```
metrics = model.evaluate(cached_test, return_dict=True)
```

Could someone please help guide through here?